# locationServicesEnabled for iOS 3 and iOS 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager

locationServicesEnabled changed from a property to a method.

This is deprecated:

```
CLLocationManager *manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if (manager.locationServicesEnabled == NO) {
     // ...
}
```

Now I should use:

```
if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    // ...
}
```

I want to support iOS 3 and iOS 4 devices. How can I check this on iOS 3 devices and get rid of the deprecated warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
BOOL locationServicesEnabled;
CLLocationManager locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
if( [locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(locationServicesEnabled) ] )
{
    locationServicesEnabled = [locationManager locationServicesEnabled];
}
else
{
    locationServicesEnabled = locationManager.locationServicesEnabled;
}
```

As a fix/work around.

Using the compiler defines will cause you issues when using the minimum deployment target to allow older OS versions access to your application.

Comment: I tried your approach, but `locationServicesEnabled` is always YES whether the general location services are enabled or not. I checked the other approach and he never gets in here `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > __IPHONE_3_1` (tested on iPod Touch 2G with iOS 4.1) It seems that you are right with the minimum deployment target.

Comment: Now I tested with the iPad, but the iPad is also hitting the method and not the property.

Comment: Base SDK is 4.1 and deployment target is 3.0

Comment: If `respondsToSelector` returns true I assume everything is working correct. Seems to be an error in the docs, because this should work only for iOS 4 and above.

Comment: That is peculiar.

We were getting crashes on our apps when they were deployed on devices where iOS < 4.0.

The above solution resolved the crashes (the warnings are unlikely to disappear, but there's not really a way around that).

Does the code cause a crash on your older OS devices?

Comment: Also, as far as respondsToSelector returning true goes, both the property and the method have the same name/method signature, so that makes some sense (@synthesize will turn the .locationServicesEnabled property in to a method - locationServicesEnabled)

Comment: This is wrong. You are completely missing the point. Accessing a property through dot notation and through a method are *exactly the same*: `locationManager.locationServicesEnabled` and `[locationManager locationServicesEnabled]` are exactly the same. The issue here is that in iOS 3, it was a property (method) on an instance, and in iOS 4+, you are supposed to use a *class* method (Yes, method on the *class* CLLocationManager.)

Answer (score 5):

Since the property 'locationServicesEnabled' is just deprecated, it is still available for use (for an undetermined amount of time). To handle the situation dynamically you need to provide a defensive solution.  Similar to the solution above, I used:

```
BOOL locationAccessAllowed = NO ;
if( [CLLocationManager instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(locationServicesEnabled)] )
{
    // iOS 3.x and earlier
    locationAccessAllowed = locationManager.locationServicesEnabled ;
}
else if( [CLLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(locationServicesEnabled)] )
{
    // iOS 4.x
    locationAccessAllowed = [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] ;
}
```

The call to 'instancesRespondToSelector' checks to see if the property is still available, then I double-check that the class itself supports the method call (being a static method it will report YES).

Just another option.

Answer (score 2):

**Editted:**

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > __IPHONE_3_1
  #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED > __IPHONE_3_2
    if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    // ...
    }
  #else
    CLLocationManager *manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    if (manager.locationServicesEnabled == NO) {
       // ...
    }
  #endif
#else
CLLocationManager *manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if (manager.locationServicesEnabled == NO) {
     // ...
}
#endif
```

Comment: Ah, because when I build my app, we usually use 3.1.3, which means we can recognize the constant __IPHONE_3_1 but because 3.1.3 will be equals to 3.1 so it will go to the else branch. The reason is also 3.1.3 is the highest iphone sdk before 4.0 (3.2 is only for ipad)

Comment: What would be if the app would run on an iPad?

Comment: What is the iPad style, likes the iphone 3.1.3 or 4.0?

Comment: What do you mean with iPad style? I thought iOS 3.2 is running and this would mean the else part would be executed. I don't know much about iPad development, because I'm coding for iPhone and iPod devices. But I think it is possible to install my app on an iPad. Then the else part would be executed. But this shouldn't be a problem, because deprecated doesn't mean the method isn't there. So the code would work?

Comment: No, if you run the code in iPad, the if part will run and then if iOS 3.2 doesn't support that yet, your code gonna crash. So, I want to ask if iOS 3.2 supports the first or the second style

Comment: Hmm, iPad has iOS 3.2.2. Because (nearly) the same SDK as the iPhone is used, I think the docs are valid:
>Availability
>Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>Deprecated in iOS 4.0.
That mean the if part will be executed and the app crashes (as you said). So it supports the second style (else part) I think.

Comment: The editted code should work. Because first, in SDK 3.1, the part of testing for 3.2 will not run and it will be ok.

Comment: Don't I need an else part (the same as the other else part) for the inner if? Because the check for locationServicesEnabled for the iPad never takes place.

Comment: You are right, you need it because if it is iPad 3.2, there is nothing run, no if is true. A little bit duplication of code but you can refactor it

Comment: I think I'll write a method for the else part. Thanks!